# Is there console mode in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, command-line, console

Is there something like Linux console in Mac OS X? Like "terminal", but without running graphics environment.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Yes. At the login screen, login as `>console` with an admin password.

To get the user name field, open the Login Options in System Preferences and change the default login window display option:

[image]

Comment: Gotta try this.

Comment: Never thought you could! You get my vote.

Comment: nice one!  never thought of that

Comment: what is admin password? I only have password to my account.

Comment: Nice! It worked with my own password, although I had to use `>console` without space after greater-than symbol.

Comment: As @Peter said I edit @mipadi answer and omit space, if you think the space still required tell to put it again.

Comment: +1, interesting. Additional limitations: Only works when no user is already logged in. And you obviously need to have "Name and password" (instead of "List of users") selected in Accounts -> Login Options.

Comment: In Mountain Lion at least, it seems you can do `>console` without a password.

Comment: Wow. This is interesting +1

Comment: Still exists in Mavericks. Use without password.

Comment: Every time I try this it shows the console briefly then blanks the screen.