# >console does not work

Tags: macos, command-line, login-screen

I have [enabled the login window](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2443/is-there-console-mode-in-mac-os-x) so that the username and password must be entered to login to an account. However, when I switch out of my user and type >console into the username field, the screen flashes white and nothing happens.

Why is this happening? Can I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I, too, had this problem.
The way I fixed it was to log out of all accounts on my Mac. After this, >console login worked flawlessly.