# Console Mode from Desktop

Tags: macos, command-line, performance

With most linux distros you can hit control + alt + F1 or the like, and get a Console. This is really useful when your X11 / display manager freezes, because you can restart that process / service in a couple of seconds and be back in.

Is there a way to do the same thing with mac (10.8.2)? It's pretty annoying to see your display freeze and know that your kernel is likely chugging along just fine..

I looked around for answers, but [all I could find is the login window hack](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2443/is-there-console-mode-in-mac-os-x).

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want quick access to a terminal, or a way to kill unresponsive programs?

Comment: Restart the window server when it's unresponsive/ recovery terminal. I suppose I could run an ssh server and get into it from my phone or something, but that's a security risk and quite roundabout.

Comment: Restarting the windowserver kills all GUI apps. How often do you find yourself in a situation where restarting the windowserver is required? Maybe there is another problem to be solved? In those cases a reboot probably would be better.

Comment: @Gerry - _'Restarting the windowserver kills all GUI apps'_ right, but shouldn't kill things like GNU Screen or what have you. Probably right, just curious if there is a simple way.

Comment: @pnovotnak it will kill screen as that would be launched from terminal which is killed. OS X != Linux

Comment: Very good point, application would be parent process. For this to be useful you'd have to be careful to disown any processes you wanted to keep. Might as well get a VM for yourself at that point, since what you're looking for is redundant power. Furthermore, when I asked the question I had a spinning disk and boot took a few minutes. Can you even buy a Mac anymore without at least a hybrid drive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No - not only can't you toggle this from your session once logged in, but you actually have to log out of all other graphical based user-sessions before the **>console** shortcut will work.

- [>console does not work](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/85742/console-does-not-work)