# How to make terminal maximize at open?

Tags: macos, terminal

By right clicking its icon, I can make terminal.app "Open at Login". But I want to maximize the terminal window when it's opened. So it will be very cool when I login: Imagine an OS X without GUI! (at least it seems so.)

Any advice?

Comment: Graphics is what makes OS X cool :)  for no graphics try console mode http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2443/is-there-console-mode-in-mac-os-x

Comment: @Mark But I cannot use it in 10.10.5! I swear there are no other users log in, because I tried this after restarting my Macbook Air!

Answer (score 3):

If you go to Preference inside Terminal, then inside Profiles and then Window you can set the default windows size.

[image]

Knowing that you are setting the size for the default window, every time you open it all the default settings will be applied.

Comment: frankly speaking, this is not what OP asking, the question is maximize, not how to set window size at W width and H height

Comment: @http8086 The window will not overflow your screen size, so you can just put a large value like 1,000 for each and it will fill the entire screen.