# How to logout from console and turn into login screen

Tags: ssh, login, console

Based on the [link](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2443/is-there-console-mode-in-mac-os-x), I can login in console mode. And then I can ssh into it from another computer.

If I want to log out the console back to the login screen how can I do that?

Comment: Does `logout` not work?

Comment: You mean type `logout` in terminal? I tried, but nothing happens.

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting.

Comment: @JMY1000, I use putty to ssh the mac console, when I type `logout` in terminal, the putty closed. This means `logout` didn't logout the remote macos, but logout the local terminal.

Answer (score 1):

If you've enabled Remote Login on the destination host there is no need to login to console mode and logout to the login screen to afterwards ssh to it.

Depending on the users allowed in *System Preferences* -> *Sharing* -> *Remote Login* -> *Allow access for:* either all or only some of the users can do so after booting to the login screen.

Comment: One reason I use console mode is I don't need to worry about the auto sleep. In your case, I will get `: Connection refused` since the mac sleep. but in the console mode, it will not sleep and I can ssh to it anytime.